# Create reference to variable based on another variable name in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Assume I've got these variables in a bash script:

```
path_family="/home/family"
path_family_log="/var/log/family.log"
path_friends="/home/friends"
path_friends_log="/var/log/friends.log"
path_pets="/home/pets"
path_pets_log="/var/log/pets.log"
```

I want to create a for loop where I could do something like the following:

```
for TYPE in family friends pets
do
  for FILE in $path_<TYPE>
  do
    cat $FILE >> $path_<TYPE>_log
  done
done
```

Obviously this isn't correct code, just most direct way to express what I want. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do the substring substitution on the variable name and have it work as intended.

Comment: Associative arrays like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452760/70524 might be the best option

Comment: @muru I've seen that thread but can't figure out the substring part whereas that example is a full variable name

Comment: `TYPE=family; var=path_$TYPE; echo ${!var}`. But arrays would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using associative arrays instead:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -
typeset -A dir log # declare both variables as associative arrays
dir=(
   [family]=/home/family
  [friends]=/home/friends
     [pets]=/home/pets
)
log=(
   [family]=/var/log/family.log
  [friends]=/var/log/friends.log
     [pets]=/var/log/pets.log
)
for type in "${!dir[@]}"
do
  cat -- "${dir[$type]}/somefile" >> "${log[$type]}"
done
```

(`"${!array[@]}"` being the ksh syntax to retrieve the list of keys of an array (in no particular order)).

Or more legibly in zsh (which has had associative arrays decades before bash):

```bsh
#! /bin/zsh -
typeset -A dir log
dir=(
  family  /home/family
  friends /home/friends
  pets    /home/pets
)
log=(
  family  /var/log/family.log
  friends /var/log/friends.log
  pets    /var/log/pets.log
)
for type in ${(k)dir}
do
  cat -- $dir[$type]/somefile >> $log[$type]
done
```

With ksh93 (from which bash borrowed its associative array syntax), you could also use associative arrays of compound variables:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
conf=(
   [family]=(dir=/home/family;  log=/var/log/family.log)
  [friends]=(dir=/home/friends; log=/var/log/friends.log)
     [pets]=(dir=/home/pets;    log=/var/log/pets.log)
)
for type in "${!conf[@]}"
do
  cat -- "${conf[$type].dir}/somefile" >> "${conf[$type].log}"
done
```

Comment: What does `typeset -A dir log` do in this?

Comment: @TMC it makes associative arrays

Comment: can you explain when you use `!` when referencing an item in the array vs when you don't? e.g. in the for loop declaration you use `"${!dir[@]}"`

Comment: @TMC, `"${!a[@]}"` is the ksh syntax to retrieve the list of keys of an array, equivalent to zsh's `k` parameter expansion flag (`${(k)a}`). See edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you! this is very helpful.  Another question. When do I need to surround a reference to the associative array with double quotes or not? is it if I want expansion of a variable first before evaluation of the array?  e.g. `"${dir[$type]}"` vs `${dir[family]}` is correct use of double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind of your provided variables and below code will achieve what you're looking for. I hope this may help you and other now and in future.

Bash Multiline:

```
for TYPE in family friends pets 
do  
    for FILE in $(eval echo "\$path_$TYPE/*")
    do 
        cat $FILE >> $(eval echo "\$path_${TYPE}_log")
    done
done
```

*Single Liner*

```
for TYPE in family friends pets ;do  for FILE in $(eval echo "\$path_$TYPE/*"); do cat $FILE >> $(eval echo "\$path_${TYPE}_log") ;done ; done
```