# how to print content of a file with environmental variables interpreted

Tags: linux, files

This question is similar to this one:
[Is it possible to print the content of the content of a variable with shell script? (indirect referencing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452723/is-it-possible-to-print-the-content-of-the-content-of-a-variable-with-shell-scri)

In a file that is

```
a=${env1}is a good ${env2}
b=${env3}is a good ${env2}
```

I would like to show content of this file to:

```
a=tom is a good cat
b=jerry is a good mouse
```

I tried this:

```
tmp=`cat a.conf`
echo $tmp # environmental variables are not interpreted, and file format changed, hard to read
echo ${!tmp} # no ...
```

Besides, above idea is kinda detour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file that looks like this:

```
a=${env1} is a good ${env2}
b=${env3} is a good ${env4}
```

And you want to produce output with the variables substituted, you use the `envsubst` command, which is part of the `gettext` package. Assuming the above is in `example.txt.in`, we could run:

```
env1=tom env2=cat env3=jerry env4=mouse envsubst < example.txt.in
```

And get as output:

```
a=tom is a good cat
b=jerry is a good mouse
```

---

If `ensubst` isn't available, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp scriptXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -f $tmpfile' EXIT

cat > "$tmpfile" <<END_OUTSIDE
cat <<END_INSIDE
$(cat)
END_INSIDE
END_OUTSIDE

sh "$tmpfile"
```

Name the script something like `envsubst.sh`, and run it similarly to the previous example:

`env1=tom env2=cat env3=jerry env4=mouse sh envsubst.sh < example.txt.in`

Comment: `./a.sh < file`  ;)  Mostly that script works, except that it seems to miss default value when environment variable is missing, like this `${env1:dog}` would be interpreted as dog when env1 is missing in `printenv`

Comment: @Tiina your shell syntax there is incorrect; you want `${env1:-dog}`.